# Is it incorrect to apply Green's Theorem to find the "area enclosed" by the graph of a complex-valued relation?

Tags: complex-analysis

As an example of a complex-valued relation, consider $$x^{2}+y^{2}=-R^{2}$$ where $R$ is a real number and $(x,y)$ is a pair of complex numbers.

A parametrization of this relation is $$f_1\left(t\right)=\left(±iR\cos\left(t\right),±iR\sin\left(t\right)\right)$$

or, alternatively $$f_2\left(t\right)=\left(±iR\cos\left(t\right), ∓iR\sin\left(t\right)\right)$$

Using $f_1(t)$ and naively applying Green's Theorem, we get that $$\int_{0}^{2\pi}x\frac{dy}{dt}dt=\int_{0}^{2\pi}\left(\pm iR\cos\left(t\right)\right)\left(\pm iR\cos\left(t\right)\right)dt=-\pi R^{2}$$

My question then is this: is it correct to say that the area enclosed by the graph is $-\pi R^{2}$?

My guess is no. And my guess is that there are serious problems with trying to naively apply Green's Theorem here.

Comment: what do you mean by the area enclosed by the above - if $x,y$ are complex they define a complex surface (so a $4$ d real object)

Comment: @Conrad I guess what I'm getting at is that there is no applicable notion of enclosed area when it comes to the curve $x^{2}+y^{2}=-R^{2}$. And thus, attempting to evaluate such an "enclosed area" with a naive application of Green's Theorem leads to nonsense

Comment: @Conrad though I suppose one can arbitrarily choose to formally define an "enclosed pseudoarea" for complex-valued relations. In such a situation, the "enclosed pseudoarea" of $x^{2}+y^{2}=-R^{2}$ would indeed be $-\pi R^{2}$. It would just be a formal construct, not actually representing an area actually enclosed by any curve